# Can you change the values of a class by passing it in?

Tags: c#, class, xna, pass-by-reference

I've searched Stack Overflow for this, and I found an answer with conflicting answers and nothing answered straightforward.

This is in Microsoft XNA. A Vector2 is a class that can hold an X and a Y.
The function is seeing if the square in it's respect direction is empty. if it is, move in the respective direction. the NORTH function subtracts 1 to the location's y value. It adds 2 to the vector, but it won't transfer onto the screen itself and move the piece. Is the problem that I can't edit the vector's value like this, I need to return it and set it that way?

```
public static Boolean domove(Vector2 location, int[,] board, char dir) //won't work, I cant edit it's values like this.
{
    if (dir == 'N')
    {
        if (board[(int)location.X, (int)location.Y - 1] == 1) { NORTH(location); Console.WriteLine(location); return true; } //if the square ahead, which would be a potential wall, is 0, or unoccupied, hop forward 2. go into technicalities of another player there later.
    }
    else if (dir == 'S')
    {
        if (board[(int)location.X, (int)location.Y + 1] == 1) { SOUTH(location);  return true; } //if the square ahead, which would be a potential wall, is 0, or unoccupied, hop forward 2. go into technicalities of another player there later.
    }
    else if (dir == 'W')
    {
        if (board[(int)location.X - 1, (int)location.Y] == 1) { WEST(location); return true; } //if the square ahead, which would be a potential wall, is 0, or unoccupied, hop forward 2. go into technicalities of another player there later.
    }
    else if (dir == 'E')
    {
        if (board[(int)location.X + 1, (int)location.Y] == 1) { EAST(location); return true; } //if the square ahead, which would be a potential wall, is 0, or unoccupied, hop forward 2. go into technicalities of another player there later.
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Vector2 is a struct and thus passed by value, not by reference. Changes to whatever you pass to your method get lost once the method ends. Pass location by reference instead.

Comment: @S_F: *Everything* is passed by value if the parameter is not `ref` or `out`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the value by reference for you to be able to write on it without returning it back again. See C# reference documentation about ref keyword: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx